# Doing Calculations In Spark(R)

Tags: r, sparklyr

I am using the `sparklyr` library.

I have a variable, `wtd` which I copied to spark:

```
copy_to(sc,wtd)
colnames(wtd) <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
```

Then I want to do a computation and store that in spark, not in my environment in R.

When I try:

```
sdf_register(wtd %>% group_by(c,b) %>% filter(row_number()==1) %>%count(d), "wtd2")
```

> Error in UseMethod("sdf_register") : 
>   no applicable method for 'sdf_register' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

The command `wtd2 = wtd %>% group_by(c,b) %>% filter(row_number()==1) %>%count(d)` works correctly, but that will store it in my environment, not in spark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument in your sequence of operations should be a "tbl_spark", not a regular `data.frame`. Your command,

```
wtd2 = wtd %>% group_by(c,b) %>% filter(row_number()==1) %>%count(d)
```

works because you are not using Spark at all, just normal R data.frames.

If you want to use it with spark, first, store the `spark_tbl` variable that is returned when you copy your `data.frame`:

```
colnames(wtd) <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
wtd_tbl <- copy_to(sc, wtd)
```

Then, you can execute your data pipeline using `sdf_register(wtd_tbl %>% ..., "wtd2")`.

If you execute the pipeline as defined, you will get an exception saying:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Window function rownumber() requires window to be ordered
```

This is because in order to use `row_number()` in Spark, first you need to provide an "order function". You can have this with `arrange()`. I assume that you want your rows ordered by the columns "c" and "b", so your final pipeline would be something like this:

```
sdf_register(wtd_tbl %>% 
               dplyr::group_by(c, b) %>% 
               arrange(c, b) %>% 
               dplyr::filter(row_number() == 1) %>% 
               dplyr::count(d),
             "wtd2")
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That helped!

Comment: @JaimeCaffarel that is funny, your answers are helping me a lot in this moment!! :) Something I dont get is what is the difference between running `copy_to` and `sdf_register`. Arent we creating spark datafranes in both cases?

Comment: @Noobie Thank you :-) The difference is that `copy_to` just copies the data frame into Spark, whereas `sdf_register` creates the Hive metadata for the dataframe, so you can check the data using Hive (from the table "wtd2" in this case).

Comment: ok thanks! is it important to create the hive metadata? what is it for?

Comment: @Noobie If you use `copy_to`, since the data are copied just into Spark, it is not persisted, so if you close the Spark session, the data are gone. With the Hive metadata updated, you are actually creating a Hive table that you can query later on.

Comment: ohhh OK... then I need to figure out a way to erase these HIVE tables. do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Noobie You can delete it directly from the Hive console, for instance using `DROP TABLE your_table`. I think that you can also use the `DBI` package in order to execute queries directly into Hive within R:  `DBI::dbSendStatement(sc, "DROP TABLE your_table")`, but I'm not quite sure if this query works.